# Matlab: Parsing strings

Tags: matlab

How can I turn strings like `1-14` into `01_014`? (and for `2-2` into `02_002`)?

I can do something like this:

```
testpoint_number = '5-16';
temp = textscan(testpoint_number, '%s', 'delimiter', '-');
temp = temp{1};
first_part = temp{1};
second_part = temp{2};
output_prefix = strcat('0',first_part);
parsed_testpoint_number = strcat(output_prefix, '_',second_part);
parsed_testpoint_number
```

But I feel this is very tedious, and I don't know how to handle the second part (`16` to `016`)

Comment: what about using `sprintf()` for the second part? 
e.g. `new_string = sprintf("%02d_%03d", first_part, second_part)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are handling integer numbers, I would suggest to change the `textscan` to `%d` (integer numbers). With that, you can use the formatting power of the `*printf` commands (e.g. [`sprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)).

`*printf` allows you to specify the width of the integer. With `%02d`, a 2 chars wide integer, which will be filled up with zeros, is printed.

The `textscan` returns a `{1x1} cell`, which contains a `2x1` array of integers. `*printf` can handle this itsself, so you just have to supply the argument `temp{1}`:

```
temp = textscan(testpoint_number, '%d', 'delimiter', '-');
parsed_testpoint_number = sprintf('%02d_%03d',temp{1});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your textscanning is probably the most intuitive way to do this, but from then on what I would recommend doing is instead converting the scanned `first_part` and `second_part` into numerical format, giving you integers.

You can then `sprintf` these into your target string using the correct 'c'-style formatters to indicate your zero-padding prefix width, e.g.:

```
temp = textscan(testpoint_number, '%d', 'delimiter', '-');
parsed_testpoint_number = sprintf('%02d_%03d', temp{1});
```

Take a look at the [C sprintf() documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) for an explanation of the string formatting options.